# Can I have a signal generator on while it's not connected?

Tags: rf-power, transmitter, impedance-matching, testing, elecraft

The unit in question is an [Elecraft XG3 test signal generator](https://elecraft.com/products/xg3).  It puts out anywhere from -107 dBm to 0 dBm.  Is it safe to have these signal generators on and transmitting while not connected to anything, or should they always be connected to a 50 ohm load?

I want to fire it up for the first time but I don't want it hooked up to my actual rig until I know everything's good.  Can I just hook it up to a dummy load?  Or is the power so minuscule that it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to turn it off while it is not connected. Zero dBm is a power level of only 1 milliwatt, and no device will be damaged by that power level.

If it were, [the manual](https://elecraft.com/pages/xg3-sweep-and-signal-generator-manuals) would have said so.

Comment: yeah i saw no mention of it in the manual one way or the other. guess i was overthinking it.

Comment: @Paul Well, I've also been accused of overthinking things. ;-) If my answer helped you, it's customary here to mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

From Elecraft support:

"You do not have to connect a load to the XG3.  A signal generator is different from a transmitter."